# Why does the meta post about recent changes have 9 answers instead of one?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

[I'm talking about this post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) Because all users will still be able to edit that one answer, I don't see why introduce confusion (albeit momentary, but still avoidable) with sorting by votes, recent activity or oldest and on top of that giving priority to one of the answers by accepting it. If there was just one answer with all changes in chronological order, it would be much neater, imo.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 7):

Well, because answers have a character limit and eventually you run out of characters to continuing typing. You're talking about taking a system designed for Q&A and trying to rig it into creating a never-ending list of something because there's just no other good place to put it.

We generally change the accepted answer on that question to the current year every time the new year rolls over, but keeping the answers separated by year is the easiest way of grouping them together in a somewhat searchable way without creating an *even bigger* mess.

Comment: Ah right, the character limit. Ok that's reasonable.

Comment: A little off-topic. I can't quite observe a character limit in the Formatting Sandbox (some posts were archived).

Comment: @iBug I'm not sure what you mean. I believe the limit is 30,000 characters by default (it's actually 100,000 here on Meta, I don't remember why), but there is not a counter when editing like there is for comments.

Comment: "I don't remember why" - massive abuses of the QA system for never ending lists of something.... maybe? ;p